# Java Sax Parser only returning one line of a tag

Tags: java, xml, rss, saxparser, rss-reader

I am trying to parse the description tag in the xml but it only outputs one line:

```html
description: <img src=http://www.ovations365.com/sites/ovations365.com/images/event/441705771/sparkswebsite_medium.jpg alt="SPARKS: Understanding Energy">
```

That is only a small part of the text in the CDATA and I'm trying to output the description for multiple items. Why can't I get the whole CDATA?

The XML is located: http://feeds.feedburner.com/Events-Ovations365

```
package com.example.ovations_proj;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.example.ovations_proj.RssItem;


public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private List<RssItem> rssItems;

    // Used to reference item while parsing
    private RssItem currentItem;

    // Parsing title indicator
    private boolean parsingTitle; 
    // Parsing link indicator
    private boolean parsingLink; 
    private boolean parsingDes;


    public RssParseHandler() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
    }

    public List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return rssItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);
        if ("item".equals(qName)) { //item
            currentItem = new RssItem();
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) { //title
            parsingTitle = true;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) { //link
            parsingLink = true;
        }else if ("description".equals(qName) ) { //description
            parsingDes = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            rssItems.add(currentItem);//item
            currentItem = null;         
        } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {//title
            parsingTitle = false;
        } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {//link
            parsingLink = false;
        } else if ("description".equals(qName) ) {  //description

            parsingDes = false;         
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null){
                currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));                
            }
        } else if (parsingLink) { 
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false;
            }
        } else if (parsingDes) {       
            if (currentItem != null) {                      
                currentItem.setDes(new String(ch, start, length));
                System.out.println("description:  "  + currentItem.getDes());
                parsingDes = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I have added a few changes but I cannot get the <dd> information to appear.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the character data in the `<![CDATA[...]]>` sections is being sent in multiple chunks, i.e. in multiple calls to the `characters` method.

The [ContentHandler documentation for the `characters` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) mentions that SAX parsers are free to do this:

> SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks[....]

You'll therefore need to adjust your `characters` method to handle being called multiple times for the same chunk of contiguous character data.